# CSV exporting SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, csv, import

I've got a csv file that has data like these : "100","220","John","Frank"

So the delimiter is supposed to be ","  How can that file may be imported to SQL server using for example Import&Export Wizard?

Comment: http://www.rodolforodarte.com/2010/03/importing-data-into-sql-server-using-the-import-export-wizard/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Two Options, fixing this in SSIS or SQL Server.

### SQL Server Fix

Import data into Sql Server using Import/Export Wizard , use `","` as Column Delimiter.

This will import the data into sql server with an extra `"` in your first and last column.

Update you table to replace this double quote `"` with empty string. Something like ...

```
UPDATE TableName 
 SET Column1 = REPLACE(Column1 , '"','')
    ,Column4 = REPLACE(Column4 , '"','')
```

### SSIS Fix

You can use Import/Export Wizard to initialize your SSIS package.

When using Import/Export wizard use `","` as Column Delimiter. Then `save it as SSIS Package in File System` and do not `Run immediately`.

This will leave your data in First and Last column with an extra `"`. So you will need to add a derived column task to replace this with an empty string.

Now go to the location where SSIS package has been saved, right click and then select `Edit`.

On `Data Flow` pane you would see something like a  Source to `Text file` and `Destination to Sql Server`.

Delete the data flow pipe connecting both tasks and drag and drop a `Derived Column Task` and set the properties something like this.... Adding a REPLACE Function to replace the `"` with and empty string in first and last column.

[image]

Now you package should look something like .....

[image]